# Python selenium load cookies error

Tags: python, selenium, cookies

I am trying to load previously saved cookies to a new session of browser.

```
import pickle
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def load_cookies(browser):
    with open("cookies.pickle", "rb") as cookie_file:
        cookies = pickle.load(cookie_file)
        for cookie in cookies:
            browser.add_cookie(cookie)

def save_cookies(browser):
    with open("cookies.pickle", "wb") as cookies_file:
        pickle.dump(webbrowser.get_cookies(), cookies_file)

webbrowser = webdriver.Firefox()
webbrowser.get('https://www.google.com.ua')
time.sleep(6)
#save_cookies(webbrowser)
#load_cookies(webbrowser)
webbrowser.quit()
```

When I call function which saves cookies everything goes fine, file with cookies is created. But if I call function load_cookies within same code (uncomment load_cookies, comment save_cookies) I got next error mesages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\code\fifa\stoverflow.py", line 23, in <module>
    load_cookies(webbrowser)
  File "F:\code\fifa\stoverflow.py", line 14, in load_cookies
    browser.add_cookie(cookie)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 775, in add_cookie
    self.execute(Command.ADD_COOKIE, {'cookie': cookie_dict})
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 311, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidCookieDomainException: Message: .google.com.ua
```

Cannot really understand what am I doing wrong. By my understanding I am at the same domain I was saving cookies, maybe I got that part wrong. If not, would appreciate any help.

Comment: Not 100% sure the cause here, but perhaps consider not using pickle to save your cookies.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exact answer for my question, but I've found way around it. I needed cookies because selenium firefox driver by default loads new blank profile with every start. No saved logins, etc. So my first thought was to save cookies after each session and later load them up with every new session. 
But there is a little bit simpler way around it. You can just load some profile you've already used on your PC and you will have access to previously saved cookies.
Here is code how to load firefox profile, hope it might help somebody:

```
path = 'C:\\users\\...' #enter here your PATH TO PROFILE, usually it is in 
                        #AppData folder and should ends like that:    
                        #...Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\urprofile'
fox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(path)
webbrowser = webdriver.Firefox(fox_profile)
```

And you're good to go with your old profile instead of empty one. Hope it helps somebody.